# Better way to add a number to itself and print the last value only

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch the amount from database and want to store total of those amount in a variable and print that variable. I searched and got a link to add a number to itself and tried it in my code but i didn't get the output as was expected.

Here is my code..

```
 <?php
 $cid = $_REQUEST['cname'];
 $cmd = mysql_query("SELECT amount FROM fund WHERE clientid = $cid");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($cmd)) {
    $acnt += $row['amount'];
    echo $acnt;
 }
 ?>
```

The output that I have got through this is like- `10001200130015002000`.

But I am just expecting the last added value that is `2000` only as my output.

Comment: Try echoing $acnt after the while loop. You should also set $acnt = 0 before the loop starts. And you could do this faster with a SUM in MySQL.

Comment: you can print $row['amount'] outside the while loop. It will display only the last value added in the variable.

Comment: this question is confusing-

you are expecting `2000` which is last inserted value. 

But, outputting the variable `$acnt` which mentioning summation of `amount`

Comment: @Kumar you may using Insert record wizard on your page so please use of `isset` to perform your particular task on your submit button click.

Comment: I always use isset command before submitting values but still the same problem occurs

Comment: This question is unclear; on one hand you're asking for what seems to be a simple summation problem, but at the same time you're asking another question about insertion ... which is it?

Comment: Explain me these - a. `10001200130015002000`, b. `total of those amount`, c. `last added value`, d. `2000`. Question is totally unclear. You were totally vice-versa one point from another point.

Comment: @kumar Follow this link to solve you second problem on submit button http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?235322-multiple-submit-buttons-on-a-single-form

Answer (score 2):

Let MySQL do the work for you instead of doing the loop:

```
$cmd = mysql_query("select sum(amount) amount from fund where clientid = '$cid'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($cmd);
$acnt = $row['amount'];
echo $acnt;
```

Btw, you must escape raw input or use a formatting function like this:

```
$sql = sprintf('select sum(amount) amount from fund where clientid = %d', $cid);
$cmd = mysql_query($sql);
// ...
```

Or better yet, use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) and learn about prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Code:**

You don't have need to use of loop.on behalf that just do sum of amount using sql query.

```
$cmd = mysql_query("select sum(amount) amount from fund where clientid = $cid");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($cmd);
$acnt = $row['amount'];
echo $acnt;
```

Comment: One more question. Why the value get added to database just on refreshing page in ? how can we stop this?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: are you using of submit button to retrieve data from database?

Comment: Actually when ever i refresh my page the values that i had put as input in the last operation gets added to my data base just on refreshing the page without giving any input..

Comment: are you using insert record wizard on your page to insert new record in database?

Comment: why somebody just passed and voted down to all answers?

Comment: All answers except yours now :)

Comment: As you said you are using Insert command on your submit button so use of different submit button to get the sum of amount and this you can get by the use of isset on your page.

Comment: @jack I don't know why?Even your answer  is better then my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You are echoing the value each time inside the while loop that's why you are getting the amount displayed each time. Echo the amount after the while loop.

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($cmd))
   {
    $acnt += $row['amount'];
  }
echo $acnt;
```

Comment: One more question. Why the value get added to database just on refreshing page in ? how can we stop this?

Comment: Is there any insert query in the page associated with this?